# what is the config injection all about in ngService snippet in vs 2015

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

when using the service snippet in VS2015 `ngService` you get the following code.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
      .module('app')
      .factory('customService', ['config', customService]);

    function customService(config) {
        var service = {
            getData: getData
        };

        function getData() {

        }

        return service;
    }
})();
```

now all is okay but what is that weird looking 'config' that is injected into the service ? and how should i use it ?

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(config)`?

Comment: There is nothing there. I suppose you have to creat a config objet or service or somethig .. Just wondering what is the pattern that sujesten in vs